# Unable to kick out a worksheet created by default in an excel workbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I've written a script in python using `openpyxl` library to populate some number from a range and write it to excel file by creating a new sheet `resultsheet` within a new workbook `newbook`. When I execute the script, it is doing all these along with a worksheet named `Sheet` which is created by default. Upon running my script I can see that it also kicks out that `Sheet` from workbook but leaves an error. How can I do the same without getting the error?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(title="resultsheet")

for row in range(5,10):
    ws["A" + str(row)].value = row

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
wb.remove_sheet(sheet)
wb.save('newbook.xlsx')
```

Once again: the above script is doing all these as I described but leaves an error. My goal is to take care of that error.

The error the script throws:

```
C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\SO.py:9: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).
  sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python36-32\SO.py:10: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function remove_sheet (Use wb.remove(worksheet) or del wb[sheetname]).
  wb.remove_sheet(sheet)
```

Comment: Have you tried making the changes it suggests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are calling methods that are deprecated in latest version of the library and these methods will be removed soon that is why library is suggesting you to use the new methods instead. so just replace `wb.get_sheet_by_name("sheet")` with `wb["sheet"]` and  `wb.remove_sheet(sheet)`  with `with wb.remove(sheet)` and your are done

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(title="resultsheet")

for row in range(5,10):
    ws["A" + str(row)].value = row

sheet = wb['Sheet']
wb.remove(sheet)
wb.save('newbook.xlsx')
```